# Devexpress SearchLookUpEdit get column value

Tags: c#, devexpress

I can't get column value from `SearchLookUpEdit`. 
With `LookUpEdit` i can get it

```
cbMarket.GetColumnValue("MarketId")
```

in my `SearchLookUpEdit` there are two table fields. i can get `displaytext` or `valuemember`. but specified field i cant.
thanks for help

Comment: well, you can use `searchLookUpEdit` if you want to filter the dropdown list. You can find this control in `Data` section. There is also a `Contains()` function but that returns `bool`. I suggest if you want to get index of specific value you can linearly search the collection list in the listbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a value of any column, use the SearchLookUpEdit view's GetRowCellValue method or it's variations:

```
object marketId = this.searchLookUpEdit1.Properties.View.GetFocusedRowCellValue("MarketId");
```